# How can i mirror copy hand

Tags: objects, mirror

I finish making the left hand, Can it be just mirror copy the object for the Right hand with the thumb on right place?

Comment: Images of what you have so far please! Yes. You can use a mirror modifier to get an exact mirrored copy if you place your hand in the correct position relative to the 3D cursor (or the origin of your main object if you use that as the mirror object).

Comment: See also the Blender [Manual entry](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/scene_layout/object/editing/mirror.html#mirror) for mirroring.

Comment: @JohnEason Thankyou so much

Comment: No problem. You should watch some videos on mirroring when modelling. The mirror modifier allows you to edit one side of an object and the mirrored copy will mirror the changes until you apply the modifier, whereas simple mirroring just creates a mirrored copy which then has to be edited on its own.